# Can't open ubuntu directory on Windows 11

Tags: drivers, windows

I just upgraded to Windows 11 and I went on to install Ubuntu from the Microsoft store. I booted it up on my main computer and I managed to set up everything just fine. However, on my laptop when I try to access the directory C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState

I get the following

[image]

and I can't seem to open it

[image]

On my main computer, I have a folder instead and I am able to navigate to all of the files in it. I have tried using the disc mounted but I can't seem to find the drive in it

[image]

Does anybody know how can I make the "Hard Disk Image file" into a folder?

Comment: This is a question about Windows so it's off topic here. I suggest moving this question to the Superuser site instead. One thing, ext4 isn't usually compatible with Windows so I'm not sure if this will be accessible from Windows.

Comment: What is your intention for accessing the linux image? It's stronly adviced against to edit files in the linux file system from Windows. Instead create the files in the Windows part of the drive and access them from the linux subsystem by navigating to them under `/mnt`

Comment: @Smurfz87 I am trying to use VIM for my notes and I would like to paste in some of my settings from my other computer. I am having issues with pasting directly into vim and so I wanted to directly drag the settings file in the folder.